# add mask to an 2*2 nparray for value ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here's a sample nparray:

```
array([[ 0.70582116,  0.29417881],
   [ 0.65219176,  0.34780821],
   [ 0.82653958,  0.17346044],
   ..., 
   [ 0.76903266,  0.23096734],
   [ 0.65070963,  0.3492904 ],
   [ 0.63485813,  0.36514184]], dtype=float32)
```

I intend to mask on the first column that if it is greater than 0.7, then apply 1 else 0 (for second column, vice versa). So in the end the nparray should look something like this:

```
array([[ 1,  0],
   [ 0,  1],
   [ 1,  0],
   ..., 
   [ 1,  0],
   [ 0,  1 ],
   [ 0,  1]], dtype=float32)
```

How could I do it via numpy in Pythonic way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, a little broadcasted logical comparison and conversion to `int`:

```
(x > 0.7).astype(int)

array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm new to nparray but need a quick manipulation. it's working like a charm!

Comment: @JasonZhu Use `int` or `float` as necessary. If you need ints, `np.int8` might be enough, if all you want is a binary mask. `np.uint8` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple:

```
arr > 0.7
```

That gives a result in `np.bool`. To convert to `np.float32`:

```
(arr > 0.7).astype(dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.column_stack`:

```
x = array([[ 0.70582116,  0.29417881],
           [ 0.65219176,  0.34780821],
           [ 0.82653958,  0.17346044])

col = x[:,0] > 0.7
final = numpy.column_stack([col, ~col]).astype(int)
```

Since `col` consists of booleans, `~col` is the inverse of `col`.

Assuming your rows sum to 1, another way would be to compare it to `numpy.array([0.7, 0.3])`:

```
final = (x > numpy.array([0.7, 0.3])).astype(int)
```